# native c++ code returns garbage value

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

When I call a native code for first time it returns proper result, but the second time it returns garbage value.
 Here's the native code :

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_project_NativeCodes_method2(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj,
                                             jstring st) {
   const char* st1=env->GetStringUTFChars(st,0);
   string str=st1;
   const int len=str.length();
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
      if (str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122)
         str[i] = str[i]-32;
   }
   .....
   env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(st, st1);
   return env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());
}
```

And in Java class I declare native method as follows

```
public class NativeCodes(){
static{
    System.loadLibrary("abclib");
}
public synchronized native String method2(String s);
}
```

In MainActivity.java I call native method like:

```
String s1,s2,s3,s4;
s1=edttxt1.getText().toString();
s2=edttxt2.getText().toString();

NativeCodes nc=new NativeCodes();
s3=nc.method2(s1);
s4=nc.method2(s2);
```

While debugging I find s3 gets the proper result whereas s4 receives garbage value. 
I think I'm releasing the pointer properly with env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(st, st1);

But if a Log() statement is inserted between two calls for the method, both calls return correct result. For example,

```
s3=nc.method2(s1);
Log.i("String","Value: "+s3);
s4=nc.method2(s2);
Log.i("String","Value: "+s4);
```

This gives expected result. But I don't want to insert unnecessary code as there are many such native method calls made.

where am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably in the "...." code before the return. Did you try without the "....." code?